Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2024
Summary: Substrate and Polkadot Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for a special election on April 16th to bring in 2 more moderators.
For full details of the process, see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange. The timeline:

Starting on April 16th, users can nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the discussion and election tags.)

On April 23rd, if there are 3 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 3 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination.)

If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on May 1st (or May 8th, if we need to extend the nomination period).


If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.
